# how to use Laravel RedisLock？

Tags: php, laravel

I recently saw MemcachedLock in version 5.5.

but I didn't see the corresponding document on the official website.

What was the reason for this function being abandoned?

Illuminate\Cache\MemcachedLock, Illuminate\Cache\RedisLock

Comment: What has been abandoned? I don't get the question

Comment: Undocumented =/= abandoned . as you can see the function is available in 5.6 and there's no deprecation note or anything. Personally I don't like how it was implemented but it will do as a quick way to acquire  lock when using a single redis or memcached instance